# jquery exclude some child nodes from .text()

Tags: jquery

The html structure looks like this

```
<div id="parent">
    parent may contain text
    <div id="child1">
       child 1 may contain text
       <script>console.log('i always contain something');</script>`
    </div>

    <div id="child2">
       child2 may contian text
    </div>    
</div>
```

I am trying to get contents of every node except the contents of `<script>`. The result should look like this:

```
    parent may contain text
    child 1 may contain text 
    child2 may contian text
```

I've tried using `($('#parent').not('div script').text()` ,but it does not work

Comment: @ShaggyInjun - Your fiddle doesn't do anything. If you log the result of that JS it includes the contents of the `script` element (in Chrome at least).

Comment: @ShaggyInjun - It does not work. It doesn't even include jQuery. If you do include jQuery, it just calls the method, but does nothing with the result.

Comment: You are right, apologies for bad answer..

Comment: @ShaggyInjun - No problem :) At least it's a comment, not an answer. And you are correct in that the code in the question has a random parenthesis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
($('#parent').text()).replace($('#parent script').text(),'');
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QLBvK/12).

Comment: (1) Your fiddle does not include jQuery. (2) You've spelt `write` wrong so your fiddle throws a SyntaxError even if you include jQuery. (3) If you [fix both of those](http://jsfiddle.net/QLBvK/4/), the contents of the `script` element is written to the page.

Comment: Thanks! it works and is a quick fix, exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7):

You can achieve that by cloning your node, removing the script tags and retrieving the `text()` value:

```
var content = $('#parent').clone();
content.find('script').remove();
console.log(content.text());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dvHKv/)

You should clone the node in order to asure an unchanged DOM tree afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me and seems very generic [EDITED to make the procedure clearer]

```
var t = [];
$("#parent").each(function(i,e) 
    {if (e.nodeName!="SCRIPT") t.push(e.innerText);}​);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
console.log(t);
```

Instead of `console.log()` you should obviously collect the strings in some other way (array?) to use them in your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/8eu4W/3/

Comment: does not work because `#parent *` will not catch the text contained directly in the element

Comment: @Alp Nope. It works. Just try the fiddle and have a look at the console, please.

Comment: ugh. why would you use e as your object reference when it's not in an event handler?

Comment: @FlavorScape "i,e" for [i]ndex/[e]lement

Answer (score 4):

A nice small jQuery plugin: [***jQuery.ignore()***](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/hh7ya7hL/5/)

```
$.fn.ignore = function(sel){
  return this.clone().find(sel||">*").remove().end();
};
```

Use like:

```
$("#parent").ignore()                  // Will ignore all children elements
$("#parent").ignore("script")          // Will ignore a specific element
$("#parent").ignore("h1, p, .ignore")  // Will ignore specific elements
```

Example:

```
<div id="parent">
   Get this
   <span>Ignore this</span>
   <p>Get this paragraph</p>
   <div class="footer">Ignore this</div>
</div>
```

```
var ignoreSpanAndFooter = $("#parent").ignore("span, .footer").html();
```

will result in:

```
Get this
<p>Get this paragraph</p>
```

<sub>Snippet from this Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348383/383904</sub>