# jQuery: exclude children from .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given this HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="artist">Soulive<span class="create-play">Play</span></a>
```

I want to get the text content of the `a` (which is `this` in the context of my function) *without* the text content of the `span`, so I'm left with:

```
Soulive
```

If I do:

```
$(this).text();
```

I get:

```
SoulivePlay
```

How do I exclude the text content of the `span`?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

A micro-plugin:

```
$.fn.ignore = function(sel) {
  return this.clone().find(sel || ">*").remove().end();
};
```

...having this HTML:

```
<div id="test"><b>Hello</b><span> World</span>!!!</div>
```

will result in:

```
var text = $('#test').ignore("span").text(); // "Hello!!!"
var html = $('#test').ignore("span").html(); // "<b>Hello</b>!!!"
```

---

<sup>if you want it faster and you need only to exclude the immediate children... use `.children(` instead of `.find(`</sup>

Comment: Perfect! I had something similar with `:not` but I was missing `.contents()`, which is the key. Thanks!

Comment: `contents` doesn't not accept any arguments with newer jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/contents/. The fiddle fails with jQuery 1.10.1

Comment: @Mrchief *I had a small phone-talk with John Resig, he apologized for the terrible mistake and promised it will be fixed in the next version of* ;) kidding, **edited my answer!** (and thanks for notifying!)

Comment: Wonderful innovative idea, Big thanks to solve bigger looking issue within a minute.

Comment: It’s 2020 now and JQuery still hasn’t added the `ignore()`?

Comment: @Jens seems like they didn't https://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 24):

http://jsfiddle.net/r8kNL/

```
$(this).contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text()
```

Answer (score 19):

```
$(this).clone().find('span').remove().end().text();
```

otherwise, with a different approach, if you're sure that your `span` elements always contain the word "play" at the end, just use a `replace()` or a `substring()` function, e.g.

```
var text = $(this).text();
text = text.substring(0, text.length-4);
```

the latter example is a too-localized and not bulletproof method for sure, but I mentioned just to propose a solution from a different point of view

Comment: You could use `"*"` so that it wouldn't be dependent on this specific structure I think

Comment: Alternatively, you could replace `find('span')` with `children()`.

Comment: No @Roko, `children()` would be more efficient than `find()` as `children()` only traverses 1-level down, and as we're removing the children anyway, this will subsequently remove all lower-levels.

Comment: $('li.yourclass').find('span').remove().end().text(); work fine for me. Tks

Answer (score 2):

```
$( this.childNodes ).map( function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue || "";
}).get().join("");
```