# Jsoup exclude children from .text()

Tags: java, css-selectors, jsoup

I have a problem similar to those:

1. [jQuery: exclude children from .text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347779/jquery-exclude-children-from-text)

Is it possible to achive it in JSoup?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are probably looking for calling [ownText](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText()):

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Document document = Jsoup.parse("<html><head/><body><a href=\"#\" class=\"artist\">Soulive<span class=\"create-play\">Play</span></a></body></html>");
        final Element elem = document.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "artist").first();
        System.out.println(elem.ownText());
    }
}
```