# Iterating the article and taking the html with out Its anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-1.8

### HTML code

```
<article class="evn-mn-pane">
    <h2><a href="somelink.php">leborium</a></h2>
    <div class="evn-date">20 June, 2013 |  Dr.some name some name1</div>
    <figure>
        <img src="images/events/speakers/no-image.jpg" alt="Dr. Somename"/>
            <figcaption>test link tested some dummy text this...
                <a href="somlink.php">more</a>
            </figcaption>
            <div class="clear"></div>
    </figure>
</article>

<article class="evn-mn-pane">
    <h2><a href="somelink.php">leborium</a></h2>
    <div class="evn-date">20 June, 2013 |  Dr.some name some name1</div>
    <figure>
        <img src="images/events/speakers/no-image.jpg" alt="Dr. Somename"/>
            <figcaption>test link tested some dummy text this...
                <a href="somlink.php">more</a>
            </figcaption>
            <div class="clear"></div>
    </figure>
</article>
```

### Jquery code

```
$('article').each(function(){
    alert($(this).find('figure > figcaption').html());
});
```

### Result

> test link tested some dummy text this...
>
> ```
>           <a href="somlink.php">more</a>
> ```

### Expected Result

> test link tested some dummy text this...

[Tried this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347779/jquery-exclude-children-from-text)

### Tried Code

```
$('article').each(function(){
    alert($(this).find('figure > figcaption').contents(':not(a)').html());
});
```

### Getting Result

> undefined

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NGdcU/)

How to achieve the expected result?any helps are appreciated 
FYI: I am using jquery1.8.3

**UPDATE**

I want to take all other tags other then anchor tag, and expecting the result other then using clone method.

Comment: Did you try this code: `$(this).find('figure > figcaption').clone().find('a').remove().end().text();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contents` doesn't take any arguments. This works even if you add more text after the `a`.

```
$('article').each(function() {
    var t = $(this).find('figure > figcaption').contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3; //3 = TEXT_NODE
    });
    alert(t.text());

});
```

[**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NGdcU/9/)

If you want every piece of text within `figcaption` except the text in `a`, use this:

```
return this.nodeType === 3 || this.tagName !== 'A';
```

Regarding the `nodeType` property

```
<a id='a'>asdf</a>

var a = document.getElementById('a');
a.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE; //true
a.firstChild.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE; //true asdf
```

[**More on Node types**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node)

Comment: If we added any-other tags with in figcaption it will not display those content am I correct?

Comment: Do you mean you want every piece of text within `figcaption` except the text within `a`? Please check the updated answer then.

Comment: thanks this is what I expect could you explain about nodeType and why its needed? +1 for your answer

Comment: as far as Now your answer only correct I am accepting it now if there is any other better solution comes mean I will accept that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick dirty way to do this. You make a clone and remove all the children. Obviously you can apply filtering to remove certain children only. The code:

```
$('article').each(function(){
   var $cap =  $(this).find('figcaption')
   .clone()
   .children()
   .remove()
   .end();
   alert($cap.text());
});
```

Comment: yes its works is it dirty way? why?+1 for you, and I tried to achieve with out clone the element

Comment: Because you're cloning the element and making a copy. The ideal way would be to just filter the text from the original element rather than making a copy, but I couldn't come up with any elegant solution. Please mark answered if that worked for you. :)

Comment: I am expecting the with out clone, In my question also I have mentioned so that I didn't mark as answerd

Comment: A quick research revealed that we can use `contents()` method to get all children and then filter through each based on node types: `var $cap = $(this).find('figcaption').contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE; });` will get you text nodes. Take a look: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Answer (score 0):

Find and remove `a` like this (Updated to not remove link from HTML):

```
$('article').each(function(){
    var div = $("<div>" + $(this).find('figure > figcaption').html() + "</div>");
    div.find('a').remove();
    alert(div.html());
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/NGdcU/12/)**

Comment: It will remove the actual anchor content, I just want to exclude the anchor when I take the result, my intention is not to touch the original one

Answer (score 0):

The text is the first childNode:

```
$('article').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('figure > figcaption')[0].childNodes[0].data);
});
```

***[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NGdcU/3/)***

Comment: Sounds good but if any other tags added that will not displayed in this method, I have tried it already

Comment: @Thirumalaimurugan updated your question then. The HTML, result, and expect result parts.