# How to not select a span inside a class

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="one">32<span class="one_span"> Years old</span></div>
```

I want to be able to select the class one text without the span's text. Is that possible? Here's what I've tried, but it didn't work

```
 var age = $('.one:not(.one_span)').text();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you `parseInt`, JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4qT4u/

Comment: This is actually a great and simple solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/):

```
var age = $('.one').contents()[0]
```

[Here's a fiddle to demonstrate.](http://jsfiddle.net/RichieHindle/VgpEJ/)

`contents()`: *Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes.*

Comment: Doent's work if there's an element within the number "<div class="one">3<span class="cat"></span>2<span class="one_span"> Years old</span></div>"

Comment: @circusdei: Er, no, you're right.  It also doesn't work if the computer is switched off, or made out of chocolate.

Comment: you really think that data is going to be validated at all?

Comment: @circusdei: Who knows?  It's fairly likely that the OP is generating the HTML in the first place.

Comment: 'tis true, but in that case it would make more sense to add the semantic markup around the number, and select it that way

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = $(".one")
    .clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text()
```

Removes all child elments, and sets text to the remaining content.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G9SfB/
Source: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/

Answer (score 1):

To be safe, clone the div, remove the span from the clone,and get the text from that:

```
var cl = $('div.one').clone();
cl.find('span').remove();
var age = cl.text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348383/1524085

```
var text = $('div').contents(':not(.one_span)').text();
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/6pRS3/**