# css don't select child elements

Tags: jquery, html, domcrawler

Lets say I have the html as below:

```
<h3 class="search-result-title">
            This is a test
            <small class="search-result-subtitle">
                Some more explanation
            </small>
        </h3>
```

How can I filter the text `This is a test`  without the `small` ?

Edit: I am using it with the symfony Dom Crawler.

So I have `filter(a. h3 search-result-title);` But I don't want the contents of the `small` element.

Comment: Is this a CSS or jQuery question?

Comment: CSS selectors can only select elements (or pseudo-elements). Not text.

Comment: or you can use jquery .html() function too..


https://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Its a css related question. I use it in a goute crawler. I don't want the small element and its contents at all

Comment: Duplicate.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Comment: I Edited the question. This is not a aduplicate

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the content using `filter()` by giving `small` element as the parameter and then `remove()` it.

```js
$('.search-result-title').contents().filter("small").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="search-result-title">
   This is a test
   <small class="search-result-subtitle">
      Some more explanation
   </small>
 </h3>
```

Comment: any idea how to make this work as part of a find? ie `$topcols = $row.find('h4').contents().filter("small").remove();` doesn't work.

Comment: No idea, Stephen. I posted this answer after much googling and plagiarized from other SO answers.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to get text of h3 element only.

```
document.querySelector('.search-result-title').firstChild.textContent
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap `This is a test` with span tag and user `$('h3.search-result-title>span:first-child')` to select.

Comment: I use it for a crawler I can't alter the html

Comment: so you can try `$('h3.search-result-title').firstChild.textContent`

Answer (score 0):

I saw that you were using jQUery so I found this : [text without child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347779/jquery-exclude-children-from-text)

You can do something like this :

`$.fn.ignore = function(sel){
  return this.clone().find(sel||">*").remove().end();
};
console.log($("h3.search-result-title").ignore("small").text().trim());`

this will return 'This is a test'

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()` the `.contents()`:

```
var txt = $('h3.search-result-title').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3; 
 });
```