# How to extract text from div in javascript without extracting from children divs?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following html:

```
<div class="targetDiv">
    Target text
    <div class="junkDiv">
          Text I don't want
    </div

</div>
```

I know I can find divs like these and extract all of the text recursively  by doing `document.getElementsByClassName("thread")[x].innerText` (where x is the index of the div I want to extract from). This will give me "Target textText I don't want".

My question is how do I extract "Target text" without extracting "text I don't want"?

Comment: get the innerhtml , then trim out the <div>....</div> section , just a suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `childNodes` property. In your case, `childNodes[0]` will contain the text element. Use `textContent` to get the value of the text element:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('targetDiv')[0].childNodes[0].textContent;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('targetDiv')[0].childNodes[0].textContent
```

Answer (score 2):

See below code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($(".targetDiv")
    .clone()
    .children()
    .remove()
    .end()
    .text());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="targetDiv">
    Target text
    <div class="junkDiv">
          Text I don't want
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348383/4401584)

```
$("#foo")
.clone()    //clone the element
.children() //select all the children
.remove()   //remove all the children
.end()  //again go back to selected element
.text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace
Target text
by

Target text

And call getElementById("MyText") in your code

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.getElementsByClassName("targetDiv")[x].textContent`