# jQuery remove span element

Tags: jquery

my data looks like:

```
["<span id="srt-46-srt" class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>0 || Orange", "<span id="srt-62-srt" class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>1 || Mango", "<span id="srt-1-srt" class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>2 || Apple"]
```

Has someone an advice on how to delete the entire span (including content)

```
$( "button" ).button().on( "click", function() {

  var data = [];

  $( "#sortable li" ).each(function() {
    data.push( this.innerHTML );
  });

  $("#span").each(function(){
    data.remove();
  });

  console.log(data);
  jQuery.post(href="[% request.uri_base %]/api/sort", {data: data} , function(data){
  });

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Your data **Array** seems invalid since you have unescaped quotes

Comment: ? For every span is a `"` and after every fruit is a `"`. Anyway, it is basically just a string. I remain puzzled.

Comment: ya `"` at the beginning, at the end, and in between and all over the place. Which makes it an invalid Array. Also, try to create a [mcve]. Could help in answering your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my data is basically derived from a set of `li` elements that after manually sorting create this `string`. A single line looks like

`["<span id="srt-46-srt" class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>0 || Orange"` It works and I currently strip everything except `0 || Orange` away at the server but thought it would be better if I were to receive a correct JSON string there.

Answer (score 1):

So you basically want to: ***get into Array the `LI`'s text ignoring the `SPAN` elements***

> [
>         "0 || Orange",
>         "1 || Mango",
>         "2 || Apple"
>       ]

Here's an example that uses  [.ignore()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348383/383904) (*though it might not be needed in your specific case since your `span` don't have any actual content and you could simply go for `.text()`...*)
The Array of contents is than created using [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) over the `LI`'s [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) - but ignoring the `span` elements:

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348383/383904
$.fn.ignore = function(sel){
  return this.clone().find(sel||">*").remove().end();
};



$("button").on("click", function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var data = $("#sortable li").ignore("span").map(function(){
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();

  // Now Send your `data` Array to server
  console.log(data);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>GET DATA</button>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li><span id="srt-46-srt" class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">Some SPAN ICO 1</span>0 || Orange</li>
  <li><span id="srt-62-srt" class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">Some SPAN ICO 2</span>1 || Mango</li>
  <li><span id="srt-1-srt"  class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s">Some SPAN ICO 3</span>2 || Apple</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A great answer. I'll take some time to see what is going on and therefor study it more thoroughly. Much cleaner data to the server now.
Thank you

Comment: @user1037763 you're welcome. Ask if there's anything unclear.