# Extract innerText from a middle Span in an A link

Tags: html, vba

Below is the HTML I have to get the number from, but not sure how to pull only the number and not the last nested Span's text as well.

```
<li class="off" id="defense1">
    <div class="item_box defense401">
        <div class="buildingimg">
            <a title="" class="detail_button tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile slideIn" id="details401" href="javascript:void(0);" ref="401">
                <span class="ecke">
                    <span class="level">
                        <span class="textlabel">
                            Rocket Launcher
                        </span>
                        20.000
                    </span>
                </span>                   
            </a> 
        </div>
    </div> 
</li>
```

If I use the following VBA code, I get the text from both the Span I want and the inner span.  How can I just pull out the #?

```
Dim IE as InternetExplorer

Set IE = new InternetExplorer
IE.document.getElementById("details401").innerText
```

I need VBA code that will filter just the middle Span's innerText.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347779/jquery-exclude-children-from-text) to ignore a content from a selector.

```
$.fn.ignore = function(sel){
  return this.clone().find(sel||">*").remove().end();
};
```

This is the solution that I got.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var text = $('#details401 .ecke .level').ignore("span").text();
            console.log(text);
        });
        $.fn.ignore = function (sel) {
            return this.clone().find(sel || ">*").remove().end();
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <li class="off" id="defense1">
        <div class="item_box defense401">
            <div class="buildingimg">
                <a title="" class="detail_button tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile slideIn" id="details401" href="javascript:void(0);" ref="401">
                    <span class="ecke">
                    <span class="level">
                        <span class="textlabel">
                            Rocket Launcher
                        </span> 20.000
                    </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but as stated, I need VBA code that can pull the text.

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Dim sp1, sp2

Set sp1 = IE.document.getElementById("details401").getElementsByClassName("level")(0)
Set sp2 = sp1.getElementsByClassName("textlabel")(0)

Debug.Print Trim(Replace(sp1.innerText, sp2.innerText, ""))
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use `var numberYouWant = $(".level").text().replace($(".textlabel").text(), "").trim();` to get the number you want

Comment: Is that VBA though?