# Loop through ul li elements and get the li text excluding childrens

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, loops, html-lists

Hello how can i loop through ul li elements and get the text content only from the li, excepting the text content of its children?

```
<li class="lom">@paul<div class="on-off">offline</div></li>
<li class="lom">@alex<div class="on-off">offline</div></li>
<li class="lom">@jhon<div class="on-off">offline</div></li>
```

I want to get only the **@paul** without **offline**,
I have tried this:

```
var lnx = $('.cht(ul class) .lom');
for (let i = 0; i < lnx.length; i++) {
    var txt = lnx[i].textContent;
    console.log(txt + '\n');
}
```

But i get **@pauloffline**

Comment: If you control the structure of the html, wrapping the first text node in a `<span>` would make it simpler to target it's textContent. Or put that value in a `data-` attribute also

Comment: `@pauloffline`? Never pollute names with logic data. An object like `{name: "@paul", status: "offline"}` is a much better data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348383/383904 which can be used like: `$(iteratingLIElement).ignore(".on-off").text(); // @paul`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery solution using replace

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

```js
$('.lom').each(function(index, value) {
  var getContent = $(this).text();
  var replaceTxt = getContent.replace('<div class="on-off">offline</div>','').replace('offline','');
  //$(this).find('.on-off').remove();
  
  if (replaceTxt == '@paul') {
    console.log(replaceTxt);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="lom">@paul<div class="on-off">offline</div></li>
<li class="lom">@alex<div class="on-off">offline</div></li>
<li class="lom">@jhon<div class="on-off">offline</div></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the `.childNodes`, filtering by nodeType of 3 (text node), to get only nodes that are text node children:

```js
const texts = [...document.querySelector('.lom').childNodes]
  .filter(node => node.nodeType === 3)
  .map(node => node.textContent)
  .join('');
console.log(texts);
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="lom">@paul<div class="on-off">offline</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but how can i loop through more li? I want to compare every single one with a word

Comment: The same operation will work on any `<li>`, just substitute the LI you're iterating over in the place of `document.querySelector('.lom')`

Comment: but document.querySelectorAll.childNodes is not iterable

Comment: `querySelectorAll` is a *function*, you must call it. Then, with each `<li>` you're iterating over, use the code in my answer, substituting the `<li>` you want to iterate over. `.childNodes` is not a property of the `querySelectorAll` function

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery variant that uses the [**.ignore() micro plugin**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11348383/383904)

```js
$.fn.ignore = function(sel) {
  return this.clone().find(sel||">*").remove().end();
};

// Get LI element by text
const $userLI = (text) =>
  $(".lom").filter((i, el) => $(el).ignore().text().trim() === text);

// Use like
$userLI("@paul").css({color: "gold"});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="lom">@paul <span class="on-off">offline</span></li>
  <li class="lom">@alex <span class="on-off">offline</span></li>
  <li class="lom">@jhon <span class="on-off">offline</span></li>
  <li class="lom">@paul</li>
</ul>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```